# trim vs FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES

Tags: php, optimization

I've got a file of 680,000 IDs (one per line) I have to get into an array.

I'm loading it with the `file()` function right now.

I'm wondering which of these 2 methods is faster and/or better (and why):

- (a) load it with file(), using the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` parameter
- (b) load it with file(), then using `array_map('trim')` on that array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost certainly A... the parameter is there for a reason. B requires an additional function call to array_map(), and additional calls to trim() for every line, plus the additional memory overheads of having that extra character in every array element until you trim them all down again.